# Multiple Validation Rules on a single field to be merged as one

Tags: validation, administration, validation-rule

Unknowingly there are 2 validation rules created for a single field and here are the rules.

Rule1 :

```
AND( ISPICKVAL(tesname__PotentialLiability__c, "Yes") , 
NOT(ISBLANK(tesname__Due_Date__c)), ISCHANGED(tesname__Due_Date__c), 
$User.Id <> '00590000003BjWd' , /* User1 */
$User.Id <> '00590000003CkWd' , /* User2 */
$User.Id <> '00590000003BnWd'   /* User3 */
)
```

Rule2:

```
AND( 
Text(tesname__PotentialLiability__c) <> '', 
NOT(ISBLANK(tesname__Due_Date__c)), ISCHANGED(tesname__Due_Date__c), 
$User.Id <> '00590000002G1mY' /* User4 */
)
```

I tried merging this 2 validation Rules using OR condition but this is conflicting. The validation rule I tried

```
OR((AND( ISPICKVAL(tesname__PotentialLiability__c, "Yes") , 
NOT(ISBLANK(tesname__Due_Date__c)), ISCHANGED(tesname__Due_Date__c), 
$User.Id <> '00590000003BjWd' ,
$User.Id <> '00590000003CkWd' ,
$User.Id <> '00590000003BnWd'
)),(AND( 
Text(tesname__PotentialLiability__c) <> 'Yes', 
NOT(ISBLANK(tesname__Due_Date__c)), ISCHANGED(tesname__Due_Date__c), 
$User.Id <> '00590000002G1mY' 
)))
```

The other requirement is when picklist is blank(None selected) this validation rule shouldn't trigger that means the criteria is not met and hence working fine.Any better solution for this. can we use IF statement instead of OR???

[image: High Level Description of how the validation rule should work]

Comment: Why not just use two rules? There's no rules saying you can't.

Comment: 1 rule is causing conflict to the other rule which shouldn't happen. Say suppose if I logged in with User1 and the condition for Rule1 doesn't meet but condition for Rule2 meets and causing error where actually this shouldn't happen

Comment: I would also suggest to not use hardcoded ids in your validation rule, but instead reference the username or put the ids in a custom setting.

Comment: @Folkert +t for your comment

Comment: This rule you are trying to merge won't work as it is flawed or overlaped. The best thing would be re look at this business case to see why 2 of them exists. If you could come back with plain business requirement it will be easy to build a rule from scratch